# How to determine number of week of the month

Tags: linux, date

On the Linux CLI, is there a way to get the number of the week of the month? Maybe there is another way to get this with one simple (like `date`) command? Let's say that day 1 to 7 is the first week, day 8 to 14 is the second week, and so on.

Comment: How do you define the week of the month? The day number divided by 7 and rounded down? Number of Sundays/Mondays/whatever which have passed?

Comment: lets say  from one to 7 day its 1rst week, from 7 to 14 second week, from 14 to 21 third and from 21 to end of the month its fourth week. I know that simple bash script with date nad if  is nice solution for this but im wondering if i can di that with one command without doing a script.

Comment: @B14D3 your "week of month" definition is pretty coarse -- what specifically are you using this for?

Comment: For nothing I was reading man for date and that came to my mind (Sometimes I have so silly thoughts). So what will be a better definition ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `date` command can't do this internally, so you need some external arithmetic.

```
echo $((($(date +%-d)-1)/7+1))
```

Edit: Added a minus sign between the % and the d

Comment: That work fine, but I dont understand why this arithmetic returns integer ?

Comment: Bash only does integer arithmetic.

Comment: Wow didn't know that. Thx :D

Comment: I've checked your solution and it gives 5 for days >= 29 ... So it's not working the way  it supposed to.

Comment: That's correct -- days 29+ are in the 5th week of the month.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to format the comment to look nicer. Anyway, great idea to implement, however if the date is 08 or 09, it will
cause error: -bash: (09: value too great for base (error token is
"09").

Thats is because if numerical value starts with 0, it will be
intepreted as octal number by C language, so 08 09 are invalid.

For me, the workaround is to change from %d to %e, %e omits the
leading 0:

echo $((($(date +%e)-1)/7+1))

Comment: If instead of **+%d** you use **+%-d** it will strip leading zero, making code work

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

Monday First week day

```
WEEKNUMBER=$(( 1 + $(date +%V) - $(date -d "$(date -d "-$(($(date +%d)-1)) days")" +%V) ))
```

Sunday Firs week daty

```
WEEKNUMBER=$(( 1 + $(date +%U) - $(date -d "$(date -d "-$(($(date +%d)-1)) days")" +%U) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d=`date +%d` ; m=`date +%m` ; y=`date +%Y` ; cal $m $y | sed -n "3,$ p" | sed -n "/$d/{=;q;}"
```

Comment: doesn't look simple for me :D and for today it gives me 5

Answer (score 1):

simplifying Victor Sanchez's solution:

```
expr 1 + $(date +%V) - $(date +%V -d $(date +%Y-%m-01))
```

replace %V with %U if you want weeks starting on Sunday.

btw: had to use expr instead of $((...)) because the later doesn't seem to like numbers with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept external tools in your quest, try [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils/).  It's got the notion of occurrence-within-month dates, i.e. 27 Apr 2012 is the 4th Fri in Apr 2012, which just coincides with your week definition.  To get that number use:

```
dconv 2012-04-27 -f %c
=>
  04
```

`%c` (count) is the format specifier for the occurrence-within the month.  Or to be even cooler try

```
dconv today -f '%cth %a in %b %Y'
=>
  1st Wed in Sep 2012
```